# A proposition about limit and continuity.

Tags: limits, continuity

Proposition:
Let $(X,d), (X', d')$ be metric spaces. Let $E$ be a subset of $X$. 
Let $f: X \to X'$ be a function.
 Let $x_0 \in \bar E$ and $L \in X'$. 
Define a function $g: E \cup \{x_0\} \to X'$ by $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x$ is not equal to $x_0$ and $g(x)=L$ if $x=x0$. 
Then $\lim f(x) =L$ as $x \to x_0$ and $x \in E$ if and only if $g$ is continuous and the (*) condition holds: if $x_0 \in E$,then $f(x_0)=L$.

I am confused about proving the forward direction.

Here is my attempt:
Since $\lim f(x) =L$ as $x \to x_0$ and $x \in E$, for all $ε > 0$, there exists $δ > 0 $ such that if $x \in E$, in  particular $x \in E \setminus \{x_0\}$, and $d(x,x_0)<δ$,we have $d'(f(x),L)<ε$.

1.I think I have shown that $g$ is continuous on $E\setminus \{x_0\}$. But how to show $g$ is continous on $E \cup \{x_0\}$?
2. How to show the (*) condition?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Seen the new post, and appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Funcftion $g$ is continuous at $x_0$,  if $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x)=g(x_0)$. Now

\begin{equation}\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=L=g(x_0).\end{equation} The last equality follows by definition of $g$ at $x_0$.

Since $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x\neq x_0$, your working shows that the limit point of $g(x)$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$ is $L$. The continuity follows since also by definition $g(x_0)=L$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! And I really want to ask you about proving the (*) condition, i.e. if x0∈E, then f(x0)=L.  Is it a trivial statement?